# Am I using too many Load Balancers for my ecs cluster with fargate

Tags: nginx, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I have 3 services and a task definition for each service. The Nginx service is upstreaming content from my client and backend load balancers like this:

```
 upstream backend {
  server Backend-ALB-ACCNUMBER.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com;
  }

upstream client {
  server Client-ALB-ACCNUMBER.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com;
}

server {
  listen 80;
 client_max_body_size 50M;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /backend {
    rewrite /backend/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

  location /webhook {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}
```

My Nginx service has a load balancer in front of it that's being used by CloudFront to distribute it to the main domain. Is this an over kill use case for load balancers or does this make sense given that each task can be scaled separately. Also note that the ecs services client and backend need load balancers to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently "wrong" with what you are doing, but all those load balancers can be a bit expensive.

One alternative would be to get rid of the backend load balancers, and use [ECS Service Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-ecs-service-connect-enabling-easy-communication-between-microservices/) for the internal addresses your Nginx container proxies to.

Another alternative would be to use a single public-facing Application load balancer, with [path routing rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html) that routes `/backend/*` requests directly to your backend Target Group, `/webhook/*` requests directly to your webhook Target Group, and all other requests to your Nginx service's Target Group.

Comment: Finally circling back to this, forgot to mention that each service is running its own task definition, Also when I tired service connect I get a 426 error, doesn't seem like using path rules would work for my use case.